# Using Neo4j API with Blueprints

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I'm using the Neo4jGraph in Blueprints, how can I use more Neo4j specific methods from the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to grab the underlying Neo4j instance with:

```
blueprintsGraph.getRawGraph()
```

which returns `GraphDatabaseService`.  There are also similar "raw" methods on Vertex, Edge and Index, `getRawVertex()`, `getRawEdge()` and `getRawIndex()` respectively.